# React Native TextInput have a Default Value How can we update/pass DefualtValue as a Text entry when state change (onchangetext)

Tags: reactjs, native, textinput

```
this.state{  // state 
    Name:'',
}

<TextInput   
    placeholder='name'
    defaultValue={this.state.items.name}// default value
    returnKeyType="next"
    ref={(input) => this.name = input}
onChangeText={name => this.setState({Name:name})}
 </TextInput>
```

Case: when we update if text field has a text value then ok
if text field is null (no text entry) then how can we replace text field with defaultValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have a type error where you don't have an object items in you State nor a key name, your State object include only Object Name, therefore in order to access it use this

```
 this.state{  // state 
   Name:''
  }

<TextInput   
  placeholder='name'
  defaultValue={this.state.Name}// default value //editted here
  returnKeyType="next"
  ref={(input) => this.name = input}
  onChangeText={name => this.setState({Name:name})}
</TextInput>
```